# How to hide div by default but be able to show them later?

Tags: jquery

I have 4 different DIV which inside they have tables and other stuff.

How can I get it to show id="t04" by default when the page loads 
and hide all the others , but when I click on the the name it
will be able to show and hide the others?

By default I will like it to be id=t04.

```
<div id="t01" class="targetDiv">
...code...

</div>
<div id="t02" class="targetDiv">
...code...

</div>
<div id="t03" class="targetDiv">
...code...

</div>
<div id="t04" class="targetDiv">
...code...

</div>
<a id="all"  onclick="changeClass('all')">All</a><br>
<a id="corporate"  onclick="changeClass('corporate')" >Corporate</a><br>
<a id="branch"  onclick="changeClass('branch')" >Branch</a><br>
<a id="Misc"  onclick="changeClass('Misc')" >Miscellaneous</a><br>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeClass(x){
        if(x=="all"){           
            $("#t01").hide();
            $("#t02").hide();
            $("#t03").hide();   
       $("#t04").show();            
        }
        else if(x == "corporate"){          
            $("#t01").show();
                        $("#t02").hide();
                        $("#t03").hide();
            $("#t04").hide();
        }
        else if(x == "branch"){         
            $("#t01").hide();
                        $("#t02").show();
                        $("#t03").hide();
            $("#t04").hide();
        }
        else if(x == "Misc"){           
            $("#t01").hide();
                        $("#t02").hide();
                        $("#t03").show();
            $("#t04").hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Give the hidden divs `display: none;`

Comment: Avoid using inline handlers like `<a id="all"  onclick="changeClass('all')">`

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a class name:

```
<div id="t01" class="targetDiv hidden">
```

css:

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

Then you can use:

```
$("#t01").removeClass('hidden');
```

Also, if you want to unhide all of them, you can use:

`$('.hidden').removeClass('hidden')` ... instead of specifying each individually.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot more luck using a 'hidden' class with display:none. Rather than use show/hide in jquery, add/remove this hidden class. That way you can pre-set your div's to be hidden initially:

```
<div id="t01" class="targetDiv">
...code...

</div>
<div id="t02" class="targetDiv hidden">
...code...

</div>
```